# Is that possible Accelerometer 1hz update frequency?

Tags: android, accelerometer, frequency, android-sensors

is that possible to slow the the accelerometer update frequenzy to 1hz and how?

i've tried it on nexus 7 tab with this: changed the sensorDelay_Normal to 1.000.000  but nothing changed.
Thank You!

here is the code:

```
mAccelerometer.registerListener(listener,mAccelerometer.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),SensorManager.1000000);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I get 1Hz acceleration:

```
static int ACCE_FILTER_DATA_MIN_TIME = 1000; // 1000ms
long lastSaved = System.currentTimeMillis();

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if ((System.currentTimeMillis() - lastSaved) > ACCE_FILTER_DATA_MIN_TIME) {
        lastSaved = System.currentTimeMillis();
        float x = event.values[0];
        float y = event.values[1];
        float z = event.values[2];
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that one would still not benefit in terms of power/cpu-usage as the hardware is still configured to poll at a higher-rate and the kernel threads will still gather this data and pass it on to the Android framework; only to be discarded by the app (N-1)/N times. But then again, if one is doing application level programming and not at liberty to modify the Android framework internals (sensor HAL), then currently this is as good a solution as it can be i suppose...

Answer (score 0):

You can always disregard measurements except one each second. Or do you want to spare battery?

Comment: i want to slow it down because i want to measure all the sensors built in and if all working it freez the device :)
That's why i need to slow down it and spare battery

Comment: in that case, I dont think I can help you, sorry

Comment: The documentation clearly says that you might not have control on this : The rate sensor events are delivered at. This is only a hint to the system. Events may be received faster or slower than the specified rate. Usually events are received faster. The value must be one of SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL, SENSOR_DELAY_UI, SENSOR_DELAY_GAME, or SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST or, the desired delay between events in microseconds. Specifying the delay in microseconds only works from Android 2.3 (API level 9) onwards. For earlier releases, you must use one of the SENSOR_DELAY_* constants.

Comment: Yes and i run it on 4.3 so in that case how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

okay i have found the solution:

```
public static final double accFreq = 15; //15 = 1 sec
long nowA = 0;
long timeA = 0;
int tempA = 0;
public SensorEventListener listener = new SensorEventListener() {
        long tSA;

        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
            if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {

                float x = event.values[0];
                float y = event.values[1];
                float z = event.values[2];

                // Get timestamp of the event
                tSA = event.timestamp;

                if (nowA != 0) {
                    tempA++;
                    if (tempA == settings.accFreq) {
                        timeA = tSA - nowA;
                        tempA = 0;

                        Log.e("Accelerometer:", "" + x + "  " + y + "  " + z);
                    }
                }
                if (tempA == 0) {
                    nowA = tSA;

                }

            }
}
```

This is the only way i can get it to work in 1Hz!

Answer (score 0):

A custom value for the value of the sensor speed dont work well.

If you take a look into the class you will find the "getDelay"  function in every .registerListener() methode.

```
public boolean registerListener(SensorEventListener listener, Sensor sensor, int rateUs,
        int maxBatchReportLatencyUs) {
        int delay = getDelay(rateUs);
        return registerListenerImpl(listener, sensor, delay, null,maxBatchReportLatencyUs, 0);
    }
```

Wich is also defined in the same class:

```
private static int getDelay(int rate) {
        int delay = -1;
        switch (rate) {
            case SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST:
                delay = 0;
                break;
            case SENSOR_DELAY_GAME:
                delay = 20000;
                break;
            case SENSOR_DELAY_UI:
                delay = 66667;
                break;
            case SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL:
                delay = 200000;
                break;
            default:
                delay = rate;
                break;
        }
        return delay;
    }
```

So normaly it should work to set a custom value.
But if you try to use custom values above about 100 milliseconds (100000 **micro**seconds) the measured time between the events can jump up to 1000 milliseconds and stay there.  If you go for 1000 ,2000  or much higher milliseconds the time between the events still are around 1000 milliseconds.

You can use SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL (= 200 milliseconds) and catch the event if enough time passed by checking that every time (like David did)
If you go higher you should not use this enery draining approach - instead register the sensorListener catch the value and unregister it every time.

Answer (score -1):

With the [current approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19894929/319204) the application is still getting events every 60ms. Just because it discards 14 out of 15 events, does NOT reduce the battery consumption as the sensor hardware still needs to process data once every 60ms and the system receives it and sends it to the application. i.e NOT much battery savings.

*(nitpick alert)* To be accurate with the above method, one needs to pick a sample from 16 or 17 events as each event occurs at around 60ms on an average.

---

The device freezing upon registering multiple sensorEventListeners at `SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL` is NOT an issue with the Android framework (which can easily handle the scenario). **This indicates an issue with how the application is written**. The first thing to look for is a lot of cpu-intensive code within the main UI-thread. Follow the **[developer guidelines to make the application responsive](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html)** with multiple sensorEventListeners() registered with `SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL` and multiple worker threads performing the cpu-intensive calculations.

Comment: can you please give me alittle code how you're think to make it?

Comment: @David That depends on what exactly you are trying to achieve with one accel sample each second. Can you elaborate your requirement? Strictly speaking, the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19894929/319204) is "wrong" as the accelerometer update rate is still the normal rate (and not 1s as the Question asks) and its just that we pick only one of the samples each second in the app.

Comment: @David The only way to REALLY obtain only 1 sample per second is to the modify the kernel accel driver. Without doing that, one can only do some post-processing upon the values in the app. Once can drop values(as you are doing), OR sum the magnitude of all samples every second, OR calculate the sample with the maximum amplitude etc. The "right way" would depend upon what you are trying to do with the accel values in the app. Can you provide some details about what you are trying to achieve here with 1 accel sample per second?...

Comment: Also can you try passing the 3rd parameter "rate" to `mAccelerometer.registerListener()` as **`1000000`** and NOT `SensorManager.1000000` ?

Comment: To follow-up this long forgotten thread, none of the "answers" above will result in any savings in power/cpu due to the fact that one is still not actually configuring the actual rate at which the hardware sensor is sampled to be lower than what the Android framework permits. The best one can do is to set the least frequent rate the Android framework supports and discard excess samples or average excess samples over the time-period one is concerned.